# sklearn test train split - get index to filename of original list

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using the `test_train_split` module in `sklearn` to generate a random combination of dataset for training and testing. I have a list of filepaths that point to the original dataset. I would also like to know how the data has been shuffled, or shuffle the filepath list in the same manner so as to be able to trace the filepaths once the shuffled/split dataset is made available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you specify the same `random_state` in `test_train_split` and `shuffle` you will get the same order.

See the snippet below for a demonstration.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random

X = list()
y = list()
files = list()

random_state = 42
test_size = 0.9
n = 100

for i in range(n):
    X.append(i)
    y.append(i + random.random())
    files.append('file_{0:02d}.csv'.format(i))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                y,
                                                test_size=test_size,
                                                random_state=random_state)
X_shuffle = shuffle(X, random_state=random_state)
y_shuffle = shuffle(y, random_state=random_state)
file_shuffle = shuffle(files, random_state=random_state)

print(X_train)
print(X_shuffle[int(n * test_size):])
print(y_shuffle[int(n * test_size):])
print(file_shuffle[int(n * test_size):])
print(X_train == X_shuffle[int(n * test_size):])
```

> ```
> [91, 74, 86, 82, 20, 60, 71, 14, 92, 51]
> [91, 74, 86, 82, 20, 60, 71, 14, 92, 51]
> [91.64119581793204, 74.77493553783724, 86.62410189510936, 82.40452263996107, 20.22784747831378, 60.913989700418675, 71.1940538438253, 14.644282494118647, 92.97808337955185, 51.289858815186356]
> ['file_91.csv', 'file_74.csv', 'file_86.csv', 'file_82.csv', 'file_20.csv', 'file_60.csv', 'file_71.csv', 'file_14.csv', 'file_92.csv', 'file_51.csv']
>
> True
> ```

Comment: That is nice - Ideally should've tried that out first! Really awesome of you to give an elaborate demo